# Giving access to am IAM account to an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-s3, bucket, amazon-iam

I'm supposed to create a new set of IAM credentials, create a new S3 bucket, and give that IAM  account read/write-only access to the S3 bucket.

What is the easiest way of doing this?

Comment: "The AWS Console," would you believe?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest would be to login to the AWS console and create an IAM User.

1) Login to the portal.
2) Select IAM from the list of services on the console.
3) Create a New User.
4) Once the user is created under permissions you should be able to select "attach a policy". At which point you'll be offered to use a the policy wizard or select from pre-existing templates.

There are also CLI tools available (IAMCLI): http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/CLIReference/Welcome.html

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you. I just forgot to save the 'Authenticated Users' permission once I added it